# Exporting an inline-declared class function

Tags: c++, symbols

If I have the following file:

```
class Foo {
public:
    void bar() { }
};

void baz()
{
}
```

compile it, and list the symbols in the object file, I see that Foo::bar was not generated.

```
$ clang++ -c Foo.cpp
$ nm -m Foo.o
0000000000000028 (__TEXT,__eh_frame) non-external EH_frame0
0000000000000000 (__TEXT,__text) external __Z3bazv
0000000000000040 (__TEXT,__eh_frame) external __Z3bazv.eh
```

However, if I modify baz() to call Foo::bar(), then the Foo::bar() symbol is generated (weakly):

```
$ clang++ -c Foo.cpp
$ nm -m Foo.o
0000000000000070 (__TEXT,__eh_frame) non-external EH_frame0
0000000000000000 (__TEXT,__text) external __Z3bazv
0000000000000088 (__TEXT,__eh_frame) external __Z3bazv.eh
0000000000000020 (__TEXT,__textcoal_nt) weak external automatically hidden __ZN3Foo3barEv
00000000000000b0 (__TEXT,__eh_frame) weak external __ZN3Foo3barEv.eh
```

It seems that the code for the inline-declared instance function is only generated if it is called within the compilation unit, which seems like a codegen / linker optimization. However, if I'm creating a shared library, I might not be able to export the instance function (because the symbol isn't defined anywhere). That's kind of a bummer.

Obviously I can work around this and define the instance function out-of-line in a .cpp file. Is there a more elegant solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is defined in the header and if you create a shared library and want to link against it, you also need the header.

Given the header, the compiler will then compile the function inline, exactly the way it is meant to be.

There is no real problem to be solved here.